# Is there any good way to check for update on microsoft store with flutter

Tags: flutter, windows

I am developping a package for checking app version and app update availability over store in all platform. I found a way on android and iOs but not on windows.

I've spent a lot of hours creating a native plugin in cpp that is working in visual studio but i struggle to make it work with flutter as it uses coroutines.

Now I am trying to find an other solution without having to make a custom webservice that would give me the informations I want but that I need to update every time a new version is published.

I have also tried the solution given here but the last given link that's supposed to retrieve app Id doesn't work anymore.